# How can I visualize an array of very small vectors spaced on very large grid?

Tags: graphics, vector, visualization

I have data in the form

```
points = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, ...}

vectors = {{2, 2, 5}, {2, 1, 7}, ...}
```

Can somebody help to edit this data so I can ListVectorPlot a vector `point[[i]] + vector[[i]]` from a point `point[[i]]`?

Nothing seems to work! :(

The data I have to work with is:

```
points = {{-100, -100, 0}, {-100, -80, 0}, {-100, -60, 0}, {-100, -40, 
   0}, {-100, -20, 0}, {-100, 0, 0}, {-100, 20, 0}, {-100, 40, 
   0}, {-100, 60, 0}, {-100, 80, 0}, {-100, 100, 0}, {-80, -100, 
   0}, {-80, -80, 0}, {-80, -60, 0}, {-80, -40, 0}, {-80, -20, 
   0}, {-80, 0, 0}, {-80, 20, 0}, {-80, 40, 0}, {-80, 60, 0}, {-80, 
   80, 0}, {-80, 100, 0}, {-60, -100, 0}, {-60, -80, 0}, {-60, -60, 
   0}, {-60, -40, 0}, {-60, -20, 0}, {-60, 0, 0}, {-60, 20, 0}, {-60, 
   40, 0}, {-60, 60, 0}, {-60, 80, 0}, {-60, 100, 0}, {-40, -100, 
   0}, {-40, -80, 0}, {-40, -60, 0}, {-40, -40, 0}, {-40, -20, 
   0}, {-40, 0, 0}, {-40, 20, 0}, {-40, 40, 0}, {-40, 60, 0}, {-40, 
   80, 0}, {-40, 100, 0}, {-20, -100, 0}, {-20, -80, 0}, {-20, -60, 
   0}, {-20, -40, 0}, {-20, -20, 0}, {-20, 0, 0}, {-20, 20, 0}, {-20, 
   40, 0}, {-20, 60, 0}, {-20, 80, 0}, {-20, 100, 0}, {0, -100, 
   0}, {0, -80, 0}, {0, -60, 0}, {0, -40, 0}, {0, -20, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 20, 0}, {0, 40, 0}, {0, 60, 0}, {0, 80, 0}, {0, 100, 
   0}, {20, -100, 0}, {20, -80, 0}, {20, -60, 0}, {20, -40, 
   0}, {20, -20, 0}, {20, 0, 0}, {20, 20, 0}, {20, 40, 0}, {20, 60, 
   0}, {20, 80, 0}, {20, 100, 0}, {40, -100, 0}, {40, -80, 
   0}, {40, -60, 0}, {40, -40, 0}, {40, -20, 0}, {40, 0, 0}, {40, 20, 
   0}, {40, 40, 0}, {40, 60, 0}, {40, 80, 0}, {40, 100, 0}, {60, -100,
    0}, {60, -80, 0}, {60, -60, 0}, {60, -40, 0}, {60, -20, 0}, {60, 
   0, 0}, {60, 20, 0}, {60, 40, 0}, {60, 60, 0}, {60, 80, 0}, {60, 
   100, 0}, {80, -100, 0}, {80, -80, 0}, {80, -60, 0}, {80, -40, 
   0}, {80, -20, 0}, {80, 0, 0}, {80, 20, 0}, {80, 40, 0}, {80, 60, 
   0}, {80, 80, 0}, {80, 100, 0}, {100, -100, 0}, {100, -80, 
   0}, {100, -60, 0}, {100, -40, 0}, {100, -20, 0}, {100, 0, 0}, {100,
    20, 0}, {100, 40, 0}, {100, 60, 0}, {100, 80, 0}, {100, 100, 0}}
```

and

```
vectors = {{0., 0., -2.94877*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., 2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.94877*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., 4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., 8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 0., 8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 0., -9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., 1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., -3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., 3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 0., 7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.13741*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.65701*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.45312*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.2865*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -2.005*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 2.005*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.2865*10^-10}, {0., 0., 7.45312*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.65701*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.13741*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., -3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., 3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 0., 7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 0., -9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., 1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., 8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 0., 8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., 4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.94877*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., 2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.94877*10^-11}}
```

This code works

```
Graphics3D[
   Table[{Arrowheads[Small], 
     Arrow[{tocke[[i]], polje[[i]] + tocke[[i]]}]}, {i, 1, 121}], 
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

but I don't like the ouput and hopefully `ListVectorPlot` does it better.

---

@m_goldberg

Here is the data and it does not work:

```
poljez0 = {{0., 0., -2.94877*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.08265*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.21021*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.98416*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.19887*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.21739*10^-12}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 8.21739*10^-12}, {0., 0., 1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   2.19887*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   2.98416*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.21021*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.08265*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.94877*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.42494*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.64045*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.82149*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.93897*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.95435*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.82133*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.49226*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.93063*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.12865*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.12326*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 1.12326*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.12865*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   2.93063*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.49226*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.82133*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.95435*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.93897*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.82149*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.64045*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.42494*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.29899*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.86039*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.96684*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.01173*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.59157*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 1.59157*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.01173*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.96684*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.86039*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.29899*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.5854*10^-11}, {0., 0., -5.06406*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.55459*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.01789*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.38574*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.55107*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.3662*10^-11}, {0., 0., -5.6646*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.32321*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.35904*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 2.35904*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.32321*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   5.6646*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.3662*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.55107*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.38574*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.01789*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.55459*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   5.06406*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.5854*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 0., -5.93105*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 0., -7.44992*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.7531*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.28876*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.70582*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 3.70582*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   8.28876*10^-11}, {0., 0., 8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   8.7531*10^-11}, {0., 0., 8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   7.44992*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   5.93105*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.96744*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.87782*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.94658*10^-11}, {0., 0., -9.17131*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.05036*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.17951*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.27078*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.26209*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.06812*10^-10}, {0., 0., -6.29109*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 6.29109*10^-11}, {0., 0., 1.06812*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.26209*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.27078*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.17951*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.05036*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   9.17131*10^-11}, {0., 0., 7.94658*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.87782*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.96744*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 0., -7.85691*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.11406*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.58847*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.00169*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.1899*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 1.1899*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   2.00169*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.58847*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.11406*10^-10}, {0., 0., 9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   7.85691*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.32848*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.79115*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.06975*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.32171*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.65774*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.10347*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -2.66891*10^-10}, {0., 0., -3.2764*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -3.55877*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.63745*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 2.63745*10^-10}, {0., 0., 3.55877*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   3.2764*10^-10}, {0., 0., 2.66891*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   2.10347*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.65774*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.32171*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.06975*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   8.79115*10^-11}, {0., 0., 7.32848*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 0., -9.57814*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.51309*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.67028*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 0., -5.33815*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 0., -7.45985*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 7.45985*10^-10}, {0., 0., 7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   5.33815*10^-10}, {0., 0., 3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   2.67028*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.51309*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   9.57814*10^-11}, {0., 0., 7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.21623*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.01086*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.2732*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.65129*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -2.22347*10^-10}, {0., 0., -3.14553*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -4.75961*10^-10}, {0., 0., -7.91236*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.49197*10^-9}, {0., 0., -2.94876*10^-9}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 2.94876*10^-9}, {0., 0., 1.49197*10^-9}, {0., 0., 
   7.91236*10^-10}, {0., 0., 4.75961*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   3.14553*10^-10}, {0., 0., 2.22347*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.65129*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.2732*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.01086*10^-10}, {0., 0., 8.21623*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.13741*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.79051*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.65701*10^-11}, {0., 0., -5.83094*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.45312*10^-11}, {0., 0., -9.72345*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.2865*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.68328*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -2.005*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.65281*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 1.65281*10^-10}, {0., 0., 2.005*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.68328*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.2865*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   9.72345*10^-11}, {0., 0., 7.45312*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   5.83094*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.65701*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.79051*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.13741*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.21623*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.01086*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.2732*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.65129*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -2.22347*10^-10}, {0., 0., -3.14553*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -4.75961*10^-10}, {0., 0., -7.91236*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.49197*10^-9}, {0., 0., -2.94876*10^-9}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 2.94876*10^-9}, {0., 0., 1.49197*10^-9}, {0., 0., 
   7.91236*10^-10}, {0., 0., 4.75961*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   3.14553*10^-10}, {0., 0., 2.22347*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.65129*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.2732*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.01086*10^-10}, {0., 0., 8.21623*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 0., -9.57814*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.51309*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.67028*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 0., -5.33815*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 0., -7.45985*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 7.45985*10^-10}, {0., 0., 7.37191*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   5.33815*10^-10}, {0., 0., 3.72992*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   2.67028*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.97808*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.51309*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.18988*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   9.57814*10^-11}, {0., 0., 7.86329*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.32848*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.79115*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.06975*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.32171*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.65774*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.10347*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -2.66891*10^-10}, {0., 0., -3.2764*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -3.55877*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.63745*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 2.63745*10^-10}, {0., 0., 3.55877*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   3.2764*10^-10}, {0., 0., 2.66891*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   2.10347*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.65774*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.32171*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.06975*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   8.79115*10^-11}, {0., 0., 7.32848*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 0., -7.85691*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.11406*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.58847*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 0., -2.00169*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.1899*10^-10}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 1.1899*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.86496*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   2.00169*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.84298*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.58847*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.33453*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.11406*10^-10}, {0., 0., 9.3246*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   7.85691*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.67523*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.96744*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.87782*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -7.94658*10^-11}, {0., 0., -9.17131*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.05036*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.17951*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.27078*10^-10}, {0., 0., -1.26209*10^-10}, {0., 
   0., -1.06812*10^-10}, {0., 0., -6.29109*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 6.29109*10^-11}, {0., 0., 1.06812*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.26209*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.27078*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   1.17951*10^-10}, {0., 0., 1.05036*10^-10}, {0., 0., 
   9.17131*10^-11}, {0., 0., 7.94658*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.87782*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.96744*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 0., -5.93105*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 0., -7.44992*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.7531*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.28876*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.70582*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 3.70582*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.59367*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   8.28876*10^-11}, {0., 0., 8.89697*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   8.7531*10^-11}, {0., 0., 8.19101*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   7.44992*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.67217*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   5.93105*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.2583*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.5854*10^-11}, {0., 0., -5.06406*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.55459*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.01789*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.38574*10^-11}, {0., 0., -6.55107*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -6.3662*10^-11}, {0., 0., -5.6646*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.32321*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.35904*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 2.35904*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.32321*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   5.6646*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.3662*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.55107*10^-11}, {0., 0., 6.38574*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   6.01789*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.55459*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   5.06406*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.5854*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.29899*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.86039*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.96684*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 0., -4.01173*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.59157*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 1.59157*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.97483*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.01173*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.66251*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.96684*10^-11}, {0., 0., 5.00432*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.86039*10^-11}, {0., 0., 4.60745*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   4.29899*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.97097*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.42494*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.64045*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.82149*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.93897*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.95435*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.82133*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.49226*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.93063*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.12865*10^-11}, {0., 0., -1.12326*10^-11}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 1.12326*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.12865*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   2.93063*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.49226*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.82133*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.95435*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.93897*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.82149*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.64045*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.42494*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.94877*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.08265*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 0., -3.21021*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.98416*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 0., -2.19887*10^-11}, {0., 
   0., -1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 0., -8.21739*10^-12}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
    0., 8.21739*10^-12}, {0., 0., 1.57288*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   2.19887*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.67049*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   2.98416*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.15544*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.21021*10^-11}, {0., 0., 3.17712*10^-11}, {0., 0., 
   3.08265*10^-11}, {0., 0., 2.94877*10^-11}}
```

and

```
tockez0 = {{-100, -100, 10}, {-90, -100, 10}, {-80, -100, 
   10}, {-70, -100, 10}, {-60, -100, 10}, {-50, -100, 10}, {-40, -100,
    10}, {-30, -100, 10}, {-20, -100, 10}, {-10, -100, 10}, {0, -100, 
   10}, {10, -100, 10}, {20, -100, 10}, {30, -100, 10}, {40, -100, 
   10}, {50, -100, 10}, {60, -100, 10}, {70, -100, 10}, {80, -100, 
   10}, {90, -100, 10}, {100, -100, 10}, {-100, -90, 10}, {-90, -90, 
   10}, {-80, -90, 10}, {-70, -90, 10}, {-60, -90, 10}, {-50, -90, 
   10}, {-40, -90, 10}, {-30, -90, 10}, {-20, -90, 10}, {-10, -90, 
   10}, {0, -90, 10}, {10, -90, 10}, {20, -90, 10}, {30, -90, 
   10}, {40, -90, 10}, {50, -90, 10}, {60, -90, 10}, {70, -90, 
   10}, {80, -90, 10}, {90, -90, 10}, {100, -90, 10}, {-100, -80, 
   10}, {-90, -80, 10}, {-80, -80, 10}, {-70, -80, 10}, {-60, -80, 
   10}, {-50, -80, 10}, {-40, -80, 10}, {-30, -80, 10}, {-20, -80, 
   10}, {-10, -80, 10}, {0, -80, 10}, {10, -80, 10}, {20, -80, 
   10}, {30, -80, 10}, {40, -80, 10}, {50, -80, 10}, {60, -80, 
   10}, {70, -80, 10}, {80, -80, 10}, {90, -80, 10}, {100, -80, 
   10}, {-100, -70, 10}, {-90, -70, 10}, {-80, -70, 10}, {-70, -70, 
   10}, {-60, -70, 10}, {-50, -70, 10}, {-40, -70, 10}, {-30, -70, 
   10}, {-20, -70, 10}, {-10, -70, 10}, {0, -70, 10}, {10, -70, 
   10}, {20, -70, 10}, {30, -70, 10}, {40, -70, 10}, {50, -70, 
   10}, {60, -70, 10}, {70, -70, 10}, {80, -70, 10}, {90, -70, 
   10}, {100, -70, 10}, {-100, -60, 10}, {-90, -60, 10}, {-80, -60, 
   10}, {-70, -60, 10}, {-60, -60, 10}, {-50, -60, 10}, {-40, -60, 
   10}, {-30, -60, 10}, {-20, -60, 10}, {-10, -60, 10}, {0, -60, 
   10}, {10, -60, 10}, {20, -60, 10}, {30, -60, 10}, {40, -60, 
   10}, {50, -60, 10}, {60, -60, 10}, {70, -60, 10}, {80, -60, 
   10}, {90, -60, 10}, {100, -60, 10}, {-100, -50, 10}, {-90, -50, 
   10}, {-80, -50, 10}, {-70, -50, 10}, {-60, -50, 10}, {-50, -50, 
   10}, {-40, -50, 10}, {-30, -50, 10}, {-20, -50, 10}, {-10, -50, 
   10}, {0, -50, 10}, {10, -50, 10}, {20, -50, 10}, {30, -50, 
   10}, {40, -50, 10}, {50, -50, 10}, {60, -50, 10}, {70, -50, 
   10}, {80, -50, 10}, {90, -50, 10}, {100, -50, 10}, {-100, -40, 
   10}, {-90, -40, 10}, {-80, -40, 10}, {-70, -40, 10}, {-60, -40, 
   10}, {-50, -40, 10}, {-40, -40, 10}, {-30, -40, 10}, {-20, -40, 
   10}, {-10, -40, 10}, {0, -40, 10}, {10, -40, 10}, {20, -40, 
   10}, {30, -40, 10}, {40, -40, 10}, {50, -40, 10}, {60, -40, 
   10}, {70, -40, 10}, {80, -40, 10}, {90, -40, 10}, {100, -40, 
   10}, {-100, -30, 10}, {-90, -30, 10}, {-80, -30, 10}, {-70, -30, 
   10}, {-60, -30, 10}, {-50, -30, 10}, {-40, -30, 10}, {-30, -30, 
   10}, {-20, -30, 10}, {-10, -30, 10}, {0, -30, 10}, {10, -30, 
   10}, {20, -30, 10}, {30, -30, 10}, {40, -30, 10}, {50, -30, 
   10}, {60, -30, 10}, {70, -30, 10}, {80, -30, 10}, {90, -30, 
   10}, {100, -30, 10}, {-100, -20, 10}, {-90, -20, 10}, {-80, -20, 
   10}, {-70, -20, 10}, {-60, -20, 10}, {-50, -20, 10}, {-40, -20, 
   10}, {-30, -20, 10}, {-20, -20, 10}, {-10, -20, 10}, {0, -20, 
   10}, {10, -20, 10}, {20, -20, 10}, {30, -20, 10}, {40, -20, 
   10}, {50, -20, 10}, {60, -20, 10}, {70, -20, 10}, {80, -20, 
   10}, {90, -20, 10}, {100, -20, 10}, {-100, -10, 10}, {-90, -10, 
   10}, {-80, -10, 10}, {-70, -10, 10}, {-60, -10, 10}, {-50, -10, 
   10}, {-40, -10, 10}, {-30, -10, 10}, {-20, -10, 10}, {-10, -10, 
   10}, {0, -10, 10}, {10, -10, 10}, {20, -10, 10}, {30, -10, 
   10}, {40, -10, 10}, {50, -10, 10}, {60, -10, 10}, {70, -10, 
   10}, {80, -10, 10}, {90, -10, 10}, {100, -10, 10}, {-100, 0, 
   10}, {-90, 0, 10}, {-80, 0, 10}, {-70, 0, 10}, {-60, 0, 10}, {-50, 
   0, 10}, {-40, 0, 10}, {-30, 0, 10}, {-20, 0, 10}, {-10, 0, 10}, {0,
    0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {20, 0, 10}, {30, 0, 10}, {40, 0, 10}, {50, 
   0, 10}, {60, 0, 10}, {70, 0, 10}, {80, 0, 10}, {90, 0, 10}, {100, 
   0, 10}, {-100, 10, 10}, {-90, 10, 10}, {-80, 10, 10}, {-70, 10, 
   10}, {-60, 10, 10}, {-50, 10, 10}, {-40, 10, 10}, {-30, 10, 
   10}, {-20, 10, 10}, {-10, 10, 10}, {0, 10, 10}, {10, 10, 10}, {20, 
   10, 10}, {30, 10, 10}, {40, 10, 10}, {50, 10, 10}, {60, 10, 
   10}, {70, 10, 10}, {80, 10, 10}, {90, 10, 10}, {100, 10, 
   10}, {-100, 20, 10}, {-90, 20, 10}, {-80, 20, 10}, {-70, 20, 
   10}, {-60, 20, 10}, {-50, 20, 10}, {-40, 20, 10}, {-30, 20, 
   10}, {-20, 20, 10}, {-10, 20, 10}, {0, 20, 10}, {10, 20, 10}, {20, 
   20, 10}, {30, 20, 10}, {40, 20, 10}, {50, 20, 10}, {60, 20, 
   10}, {70, 20, 10}, {80, 20, 10}, {90, 20, 10}, {100, 20, 
   10}, {-100, 30, 10}, {-90, 30, 10}, {-80, 30, 10}, {-70, 30, 
   10}, {-60, 30, 10}, {-50, 30, 10}, {-40, 30, 10}, {-30, 30, 
   10}, {-20, 30, 10}, {-10, 30, 10}, {0, 30, 10}, {10, 30, 10}, {20, 
   30, 10}, {30, 30, 10}, {40, 30, 10}, {50, 30, 10}, {60, 30, 
   10}, {70, 30, 10}, {80, 30, 10}, {90, 30, 10}, {100, 30, 
   10}, {-100, 40, 10}, {-90, 40, 10}, {-80, 40, 10}, {-70, 40, 
   10}, {-60, 40, 10}, {-50, 40, 10}, {-40, 40, 10}, {-30, 40, 
   10}, {-20, 40, 10}, {-10, 40, 10}, {0, 40, 10}, {10, 40, 10}, {20, 
   40, 10}, {30, 40, 10}, {40, 40, 10}, {50, 40, 10}, {60, 40, 
   10}, {70, 40, 10}, {80, 40, 10}, {90, 40, 10}, {100, 40, 
   10}, {-100, 50, 10}, {-90, 50, 10}, {-80, 50, 10}, {-70, 50, 
   10}, {-60, 50, 10}, {-50, 50, 10}, {-40, 50, 10}, {-30, 50, 
   10}, {-20, 50, 10}, {-10, 50, 10}, {0, 50, 10}, {10, 50, 10}, {20, 
   50, 10}, {30, 50, 10}, {40, 50, 10}, {50, 50, 10}, {60, 50, 
   10}, {70, 50, 10}, {80, 50, 10}, {90, 50, 10}, {100, 50, 
   10}, {-100, 60, 10}, {-90, 60, 10}, {-80, 60, 10}, {-70, 60, 
   10}, {-60, 60, 10}, {-50, 60, 10}, {-40, 60, 10}, {-30, 60, 
   10}, {-20, 60, 10}, {-10, 60, 10}, {0, 60, 10}, {10, 60, 10}, {20, 
   60, 10}, {30, 60, 10}, {40, 60, 10}, {50, 60, 10}, {60, 60, 
   10}, {70, 60, 10}, {80, 60, 10}, {90, 60, 10}, {100, 60, 
   10}, {-100, 70, 10}, {-90, 70, 10}, {-80, 70, 10}, {-70, 70, 
   10}, {-60, 70, 10}, {-50, 70, 10}, {-40, 70, 10}, {-30, 70, 
   10}, {-20, 70, 10}, {-10, 70, 10}, {0, 70, 10}, {10, 70, 10}, {20, 
   70, 10}, {30, 70, 10}, {40, 70, 10}, {50, 70, 10}, {60, 70, 
   10}, {70, 70, 10}, {80, 70, 10}, {90, 70, 10}, {100, 70, 
   10}, {-100, 80, 10}, {-90, 80, 10}, {-80, 80, 10}, {-70, 80, 
   10}, {-60, 80, 10}, {-50, 80, 10}, {-40, 80, 10}, {-30, 80, 
   10}, {-20, 80, 10}, {-10, 80, 10}, {0, 80, 10}, {10, 80, 10}, {20, 
   80, 10}, {30, 80, 10}, {40, 80, 10}, {50, 80, 10}, {60, 80, 
   10}, {70, 80, 10}, {80, 80, 10}, {90, 80, 10}, {100, 80, 
   10}, {-100, 90, 10}, {-90, 90, 10}, {-80, 90, 10}, {-70, 90, 
   10}, {-60, 90, 10}, {-50, 90, 10}, {-40, 90, 10}, {-30, 90, 
   10}, {-20, 90, 10}, {-10, 90, 10}, {0, 90, 10}, {10, 90, 10}, {20, 
   90, 10}, {30, 90, 10}, {40, 90, 10}, {50, 90, 10}, {60, 90, 
   10}, {70, 90, 10}, {80, 90, 10}, {90, 90, 10}, {100, 90, 
   10}, {-100, 100, 10}, {-90, 100, 10}, {-80, 100, 10}, {-70, 100, 
   10}, {-60, 100, 10}, {-50, 100, 10}, {-40, 100, 10}, {-30, 100, 
   10}, {-20, 100, 10}, {-10, 100, 10}, {0, 100, 10}, {10, 100, 
   10}, {20, 100, 10}, {30, 100, 10}, {40, 100, 10}, {50, 100, 
   10}, {60, 100, 10}, {70, 100, 10}, {80, 100, 10}, {90, 100, 
   10}, {100, 100, 10}}
```

What gives me a completely empty box is

```
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Small], 
  MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {tockez0, poljez0 + tockez0}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: Perhaps `ListVectorPlot3D[Transpose[{points,vectors}]]`

Comment: Not really. Doesn't work.

This works though:
Graphics3D[
 Table[{Arrowheads[Small], 
   Arrow[{tocke[[i]], polje[[i]] + tocke[[i]]}]}, {i, 1, 121}], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]

But I don't like the output and looking at pictures, I have a feeling that LisVectorPlot will do it better.

Comment: Since you have an output already, please provide your data and the code/output you have and then say what you're not satisfied with. You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: Good point. I added data in the original post.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok, so I guess I can't plot my data with ListVectorPlot. But, let me ask you, is there a better way than what I have showed? Because I really don't like that I see arrowheads only. It makes it so hard to see what is actually going on.

Comment: It is actually not. That is what my calculations show and physically speaking it almost makes sense. Of course, you couldn't know that but at the same time I was blaming mathematica for the problems :D

Comment: In my opinion this question is not a duplicate. It is not about plotting a 3D vector field. The original title was misleading. I have retitled it with a title I think much more appropriate. I advocate reopening the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your original idea of using `Graphics3D` was the right idea. To get output from `Graphics3D` that looks good, you need to scale up the z-axis. I did that with the option [`BoxRatios`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoxRatios.html) and got the following.

```
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Small], MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {points, points + vectors}]},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.25},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: vectors]

#### Update (edited)

I have worked with your 2nd data set. My conclusion is that you don't see any results because of a `Graphics3D` numerics problem (which may be a bug). As a work-around for the problem, I suggest scaling up the z-coordinates of the vectors and relabeling the z-axis with custom ticks. Here is one possible way to do it.

```
vecs = poljez0; pts = tockez0 (* renaming data posted in the question *)

With[{scale = 10^11, ϵ = Max[vecs[[All, 3]]]}, 
  Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Small], MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {pts, pts + scale vecs}]},
    Ticks -> 
      {Automatic, Automatic, 
        {{10 - scale ϵ, "10 - ϵ"}, {10, "10"}, {10 + scale ϵ, "10 + ϵ"}}},
    PlotRangePadding -> 20,
    PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"ϵ = ", ϵ}], Black, 14, "SR"],
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z }]]
```

[image: vector-grid]

Comment: A lot better than what I have! Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, Can you be a bit more specific how you scaled the Z axis? Because I have another graph with values around 10^(-11) and I can't get it right... :/

Comment: @skrat. Experiment with `BoxRatios`. Start with `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}` and adjust the z coordinate to your liking.

Comment: I did, but I can only see arrows for BoxRatios->{1,1,0.00001} but with a picture like this, everything looks 2D and it doesn't help too much.

Answer (score 2):

You get meaningful output by multiplying the tiny values of `poljez0` with some large number and limiting the Z-`PlotRange`:

```
Graphics3D[{Darker@Blue,
  Arrowheads[0.02],
  MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {tockez0, poljez0*10^12 + tockez0}]},
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 FaceGrids -> {{0, -1, 0}},
 FaceGridsStyle -> Dashed,
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Or, partitioning your data, work with `ListVectorPlot3D`:

```
ListVectorPlot3D[
 Partition[
  Partition[
   Partition[Flatten@Transpose[{tockez0, poljez0*10^11 + tockez0}], 
    3], 30], 4],
   VectorScale -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.3]},
   VectorPoints -> 10,
   VectorColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, n}, Hue[x, z, 1]],
   VectorColorFunctionScaling -> {True, True},
   PlotTheme -> "Marketing"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, but I was hoping to get right numbers on the z axis too..